# User input send to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have made a table with JavaScript where users can input numbers.
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDsMC.png). Now I made this table dynamically with JavaScript.

```
const container = document.getElementById("container");
console.log(container)

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    //cell.innerHTML = "<input type='text' value='' class='buckinput'/>"
    container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
    container.appendChild(cell).contentEditable = true

    cell.onkeydown = function (event) {
      if (event.key == 'Enter') {
        this.blur();
      }
    };
  };
};

makeRows(11, 9);
```

What I try to do is get the user values out of the `divs` and send them to a database.
the question is how to get these user input values out of the `divs` and send them to the database ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: probably AJAX is going to be the best solution here. Or you could just wrap the whole table in a form and submit it the normal way. It's not really clear exactly where you are stuck. What research have you done, what have you tried, what is puzzling you precisely?

Comment: @ADyson I am stuck getting the user input out of the divs i have read that you can not send div values to a database only input fields. this is where I am stuck. every time a user inputs a new value it needs to get send to the database. I am just looking for the best way to program this table so every user value is send to the database.

Comment: "i have read that you can not send div values to a database only input fields"...that's right. But if you're saying the user can input values, are they inputting it somewhere else, and then you copy it into the table, into divs? If so then, when you copy it, you can store the data in a variable, and then send that variable's data to the server via AJAX.

Comment: Or are you using contenteditable divs for the input, which the code suggests you might be? It's best for us to be clear. If you're using contenteditable divs then, when the user clicks to say they've finished entering that row, you can handle that event, then get the content out of the divs using Javascript, collect them into an object, and then send that to the server via AJAX.

Comment: @ADyson ineed I am using Contenteditable divs

Comment: ok so, how do you currently detect when the user has finished editing the row, and the data is ready to send? Do they have to press a button or something?

Comment: @ADyson that's where I am pretty much stuck on how to get that data ready to send. and for the The detection I probably use something like `$input.on('keydown', function () {
  do something
}); `

Comment: If you don't have some kind of button or checkbox for the user to indicate that they have finished editing, then you likely need one. Otherwise you can't be sure when they are ready, because there are multiple fields, and they might want to edit them in a different order, or go back and check things and change them if they realise there's a mistake.  So once you have a button like that, then to start with it's a simple matter of handling a "click" event on that button.

Comment: so basically its when button is clicked get values out of Divs and put it in a ajax request to the databse. the thing is how do you get those values out of those divs?

Comment: the `innerText` property of an element can be used to gets its text content, if that's what you're asking. Or are you asking how to identify the correct divs in the first place?

Comment: so i made a button in html. `document.getElementById("done_editing").addEventListener("click", send_values);

function get_values(){
get the values out of the divs
  
}` this is what you mean correct ?

Comment: Yes that's the idea. Although your event listener mentions a function called send_values, but then you've defined one call get_values, so the names don't match.

Comment: `document.getElementById("done_editing").addEventListener("click", get_values);

function get_values(){
 let divobj=document.getElementsByClassName('grid-item').innerText
 console.log(divobj)


}` well this gives me undefined now

Comment: edit : when i console log `let divobj` it gives me an HTMLcolletion

Comment: yes because that's exactly what is is - a collection of all the elements which have that class. You need to loop through them and collect the contents of each one individually.

Comment: it is indeed giving me the text back but also the text of my column headers because their class is `grid-item columnheader` and i am calling only `grid-item` weird that it also takes the other but oh well thank you for your help

Comment: well then maybe give your divs an extra class which is not ever given to any other elements. (You can make a class name up, it doesn't have to have any kind of CSS rules attached to it). P.S. It's not weird that it takes the others - you told it to find all elements with that class name. The fact those elements also happen to have other classes defined on them is irrelevant - they have the class you specified, that's all that it considers. To be clear: `grid-item columnheader` is **two separate** class names, not one single one. An element can be given as many classes as you like.

Comment: Thank you for all your help I have made it work. now i am going to educate myself on how to send those text contents into an ajax request :p

Comment: Details like what is in the comments here would be good to add to the question. Also if you have solved the problem someone should post an answer so it can be set as the correct answer :)